# React Router : can I map Routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have three Components : AitemComponent, BitemComponent and CitemComponent. And an Items array contains the list of items.

I want to render the appropriate component according **to the route** ?
Each Component catch the route parameters and return the item's view.

```
(this.state.items) ?
                this.state.items.map(item => (
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path={"/a/"+item.id} component={AitemComponent} />
                    <Route path={"/b/"+item.id} component={BitemComponent} />
                    <Route path={"/c/"+item.id} component={CitemComponent} />
                  </Switch>
                ))
              : null
```

I know that I can instead of the `<Route />` just set `<Aitem id="item.id" />`. But I want to handle everything using router, is it possible ? Is there any other way if this method sounds weird ?

This won't work and this is the output :

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

Thanks !

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Why dont you just use <Route path={"/a/:itemId"}? The code you are using, would render one Route with path a/2903812309 for example, for every item. You should use a generic route, instead of creating a route for each possible item

Comment: @iagowp Indeed, I answered my own question below. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, It's about a list not a page for each item. Thus; a list of items should be written this way, instead of the code I wrote above :

```
//generate your this.state.search_result
//put your component here : this.state.component
//pass the parameters in the Component Tag
//Example :
{
                    (this.state.search_result) && (this.state.component) &&
                      this.state.search_result.map((item, key) => (
                          <this.state.component {...this.props} 
                                                aria_expanded={this.state.idofthis === item.id ? true : false}
                                                imageOfThis={(item.images && item.images[0]) ? item.images[0].url : null}
                                                href={(item.href) ? item.href : null}
                                                duration_ms={(item.duration_ms) ? item.duration_ms : null}
                                                key={key} 
                                                id={item.id} 
                                                name={item.name} 
                                                accordion={'#accordion-result'} />
                      ))
                  }
```